# How do you make a form input field that grows upwards like in Facebook's messenger.com?

Tags: javascript, html, input

In Facebook's messenger.com, the input field where you type your message in grows vertically upwards once the message you're typing in wraps to the next line or if you insert a carriage return. I'm wondering if this is a default behavior of an HTML input element or if it is some JavaScript magic to make this happen. Does anyone know how this is done?

[image: Messenger input field]

Comment: Google "textarea autogrow facebook" and find a solution you like.

Comment: Hey @epascarello thanks for the tip! Looks like it is pointing me in the right direction :)